# Error while updating modules on odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am new to odoo and I am getting odoo server error while updating odoo modules. I cant't figure out where is the problem. I didn't touch anything in the source code, even i didn't install any external modules. Can y see where is the problem please. Have I to delete and re-install the database ?

Thank you.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 583, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 319, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call
return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 812, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 439, in old_api
result = new_api(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 443, in new_api
result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_module_update.py", line 15, in update_module
self.updated, self.added = self.env['ir.module.module'].update_list()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 651, in update_list
handler.load_addons()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1310, in load_addons
manifest_path = os.path.join(addons_path, module, '__openerp__.py')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 73, in join
path += '/' + b
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by creating a new database. I don't know if it is the optimal solution (because I lost all my data) but this how I fixed the problem.